# MySQL: Slow SELECT because of Index / FKEY?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing, query-performance

Dear StackOverflow Members

It's my first post, so please be nice :-)

I have a strange SQL behavior which i can't explain and don't find any resources which explains it.

I have built a web honeypot which record all access and attacks and display it on a statistic page.
However since the data increased, the generation of the statistic page is getting slower and slower.

I narrowed it down to a some select statements which takes a quite a long time.

The "issue" seems to be an index on a specific column.

*For sure the real issue is my lack of knowledge :-)

**Database:** mysql

[DB schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZlW3.png)

**Event Table** (removed unrelated columes):

- Event table size: 30MB
- Event table records: 335k

  ```
    CREATE TABLE `event` (

     `EventID` int(11) NOT NULL,

     `EventTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),

     `WEBURL` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,

     `IP` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,

     `AttackID` int(11) NOT NULL

   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

   ALTER TABLE `event`
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (`EventID`),
     ADD KEY `AttackID` (`AttackID`);
   ALTER TABLE `event`
     ADD CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`AttackID`) REFERENCES `attack` (`AttackID`);
  ```

**Attack Table**

- attack table size: 32KB
- attack Table records: 11

CREATE TABLE `attack` (

```
  `AttackID` int(4) NOT NULL,

  `AttackName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,

  `AttackDescription` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

ALTER TABLE `attack`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`AttackID`),
```

**SLOW Query:**

```
SELECT Count(EventID), IP
-> FROM event
-> WHERE AttackID >0
-> GROUP BY IP
-> ORDER BY Count(EventID) DESC
-> LIMIT 5;
```

RESULT: 5 rows in set (**1.220 sec**)
(This seems quite long for me, for a simple query)

[QuerySlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faNBq.png)

Now the Strange thing:
If I remove the foreign key relationship the performance of the query is the same.
But if I remove the the index on event.AttackID same select statement is much faster:

```
(ALTER TABLE `event` DROP INDEX `AttackID`;)
```

The result of the SQL SELECT query:
**5 rows in set (0.242 sec)**

[QueryFast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KH5N.png)

From my understanding indexes on columns which are used in "WHERE" should improve the performance.

- Why does removing the index have such an impact on the query?
- What can I do to keep the relations between the table and have a faster
  SELECT execution?

Cheers

Comment: The optimizer is probably using that index, but it's not selective. How many rows exist with an attackID > 0? Btw,  PRIMARY KEY (`AttackID`) and UNIQUE KEY (`AttackID`) is exactly the same, similar for EventID

Comment: i dont think FK has anything to do with your SELECT query. Sometime the client can take different time to return result. Correct time can be known when we pull all the data. Can you pls do a remove limit and create table for both scenario and see the difference in time ? `CREATE TABLE tmp1 SELECT Count(EventID), IP
FROM event
WHERE AttackID >0
GROUP BY IP
ORDER BY Count(EventID) DESC;`

Comment: @dnoeth
Total rows with attack ID > 0: 311292
Thx for the hints with the index, I remove the UNIQUE one.

Comment: @Koushik Roy
TMP1 created quite fast:
CREATE TABLE tmp1 SELECT Count(EventID), IP FROM event WHERE AttackID >0 GROUP BY IP ORDER BY Count(EventID) DESC;
Query OK, 9843 rows affected (0.341 sec)
Records: 9843  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: When you post a slow query to be analyzed, please also post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT ......  so we can see how the optimizer thinks the query will be processed.  This will also give everyone an idea of missing indexes (that usually improve performance).

Answer (score 0):

> Why does removing the index improve performance?

The query optimizer has multiple ways to resolve a query.  For instance, two methods for filtering data are:

1. Look up the rows that match the `where` clause in the index and then fetch related data from the data pages.
2. Scan the index.

This doesn't get into the use of indexes for joins or aggregations or alternative algorithms.

Which is better?  Under some circumstances, the first method is horribly slower than the second.  This occurs when the data for the table does not fit into memory.  Under such circumstances, the index can read a record from page 124 and then from 1068 and then from 124 again and -- well, all sorts of random intertwined reading of pages.  Reading data pages in order is usually faster.  And when the data doesn't fit into memory, *thrashing* occurs, which means that a page in memory is aged (overwritten) -- and then needed again.

I'm not saying that is occurring in your case.  I am simply saying that what optimizers do is not always obvious.  The optimizer has to make judgements based on the nature of the data -- and those judgements are not right 100% of the time.  They are usually correct.  But there are borderline cases.  Sometimes, the issue is out-of-date statistics.  Sometimes the issue is that what looks best to the optimizer is not best in practice.

Let me emphasize that optimizers usually do a very good job, and a better job than a person would do.  Even if they occasionally come up with suboptimal plans, they are still quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your redundant `UNIQUE KEY`s. A primary key *is* a unique key.

Use COUNT(*) rather than COUNT(IP) in your query. They mean the same thing because you declared IP to be NOT NULL.

Your query can be much faster if you stop saying `WHERE AttackId>0`. Because that column is a FK to the PK of your other table, those values should be nonzero anyway.  But to get that  speedup you'll need an index on `event(IP)` something like this.

```
CREATE INDEX IpDex ON event (IP)
```

But you're still summarizing a large table, and that will always take time.

It looks like you want to display some kind of leaderboard. You could add a `top_ips` table, and use an EVENT to populate it, using your query, every few minutes. Then you could display it to your users without incurring the cost of the query every time. This of course would display slightly stale data; only you know whether that's acceptable in your app.

**Pro Tip**. Read https://use-the-index-luke.com by Marcus Winand.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the unique keys, changed to COUNT(*). But the Select Statement is still much faster without you index: 0.324(index only on Primary) VS 11.93 (index on IP). Therfore I may just leave it without additional index.

Comment: Yes, I also tough about creating statistics table which are updated  hourly, maybe I will switch to it when it gets to slow..

Answer (score 0):

Essentially every part of your query, except for the FKey, conspires to make the query slow.

Your query is equivalent to

```
SELECT  Count(*), IP
    FROM  event
    WHERE  AttackID >0
    GROUP BY  IP
    ORDER BY  Count(*) DESC
    LIMIT  5;
```

Please use `COUNT(*)` unless you need to avoid `NULL`.

If `AttackID` is *rarely* `>0`, the optimal index is probably

```
ADD INDEX(AttackID,    -- for filtering
          IP)          -- for covering
```

Else, the optimal index is probably

```
ADD INDEX(IP,          -- to avoid sorting
          AttackID)    -- for covering
```

You could simply add both indexes and let the Optimizer decide.  Meanwhile, get rid of these, if they exist:

```
DROP INDEX(AttackID)
DROP INDEX(IP)
```

because any uses of them are handled by the new indexes.

Furthermore, leaving the 1-column indexes around can confuse the Optimizer into using them instead of the covering index.  (This seems to be a design flaw in at least some versions of MySQL/MariaDB.)

"Covering" means that the query can be performed entirely in the index's BTree.  `EXPLAIN` will indicate it with "Using index".  A "covering" index speeds up a query by 2x -- but there is a very wide variation on this prediction.  ("Using index condition" is something different.)

More on index creation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql